# How To Create a "Total" Row for One Column in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

So I've created a DF from file names I've pulled using the os module

The file names include dollar amounts and I would like to be able to create a row that totals just the amount in that column of the DF (index 3)

However, when I follow this code structure:

```
File_Name.loc['Total'] = File_Name.sum()
```

I get this:

```
                                                 Invoice  ...                                             Amount
30                                                  6515  ...                                             401.01
Total  0822OH082522KTR1987000084201987000084481987000...  ...  478.88550.0030.1032.3912.0432.521020.4729.1442...
```

I would love for it to look like this:

```
         Invoice         Vendor   Amount
30          6515        Expense   401.01
Total                          198556.79
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend to reconsider using pandas as if it were Excel. By adding totals in a row, you make totals to be just one more data row in your table. i.e. for further calculations you're going to have one extra Invoice data point for a large sum.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I want to find the sum of the Amount column, not the invoice column. That may be my issue, as the invoice column is just invoice number/identifying information. In this case, to treat it like excel, do I need to create the total row and manipulate Total[3]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas just released (v1.5.0) a new feature in `Styler` for doing just this. The `Styler` is used for display of data whereas a `DataFrame` is essentially an efficient memory map of data. Therefore the ability the combine and structure different `DataFrames` for display purposes is useful. The `Styler` allows for configuring formatting output differently for different tables. E.g. a column might have integer values but the arithmetic mean is usually a float with multiple decimals.

See the docs for `Styler.concat` as it discusses this use case. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.concat.html

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm very new to Python and this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The long number you get in `Amount` is probably the result of string concatenation:

```
'478.88' + '550.00' + '30.10' + '32.39'
```

outputs

```
478.88550.0030.1032.39
```

So, the first step will be to cast the column `Amount` to floats with `File_Name['Amount'].astype('float')`.

You can add the sum of `Amount` and get the *visual effect* you are looking for with

```
df.loc['Total', 'Amount'] = df['Amount'].sum()
df.loc['Total'] = df.loc['Total'].fillna('')
```

Nevertheless, I would strongly recommend not using pandas as if it were Excel. While Excel style can be convenient when working under such a heavy interface, it's problematic from a programmatic point of view: now you'll have an extra data point with a large value in `Amount` and lots of null strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I misread your initial comment.